# Table View Cell Background view keep getting brighter and brighter

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift2

hey I had this weird problem , I added a subview on Table View and gave it a background color.. When app launches the Color is fine as In the Image

[image]

But When I scroll down the cells that are below from the margin are a little brighter then the current cells Like this

[image]

After Scrolling back the first cells become more bright and by scrolling multiple times it become complete White .

[image]

Here is the Code of Table view cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventsViewCell

    let dict = componentsLoaded[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    cell.eventTitle!.text = (dict["news_headline"] as! String)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    let date_post = dict["news_date"] as! String
    cell.dateLabel!.text = ConvertDate().convertYourDate(date_post)

    return cell

}
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



    let height = cell.frame.height
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height ))

    red = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.3])
    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = red
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteRoundedView)

}
```

Comment: debug your layout with 3dview, i guess your white view is added multiple times resulting this issue.

Comment: yes you are right .. how to avoid this ? my view is Added 4 Times on a single Cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line in view WillDisplaycell

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
```

this line add white view with alpha 0.3 at every time cell will be display, multiple views above previous view resulting in more white view appearance.

Please add you white view when creating cell i.e. in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventsViewCell

let dict = componentsLoaded[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
cell.eventTitle!.text = (dict["news_headline"] as! String)
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
let date_post = dict["news_date"] as! String
cell.dateLabel!.text = ConvertDate().convertYourDate(date_post)

let whiteRoundedView : UIView = cell.viewWithTag(1001/*Your tag*/)
red = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.3])
whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = red
whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

return cell
}
```

Comment: i dont know what is the problem , its been driving me crazy as of Yesterday

Comment: are you using prototype cell?

Comment: add view you want , give view a tag and use in cellForRowAtIndexPath, by this you will not need to add view as subview. This will surely eliminate your issue.

Comment: can you please elaborate that how can i do this using code .. I mean add i did view.tag = indexpath.row     .. what to do after this

Comment: You can access your view like

UIView *whiteVew = [cell viewWithTag:1000];
rest You can use this view as desire. no need to add this view as subview again

Comment: see my edited answer, no need for view willdisplaycell now, you may eliminate that method if no further use.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
 on cell.viewWithTag line

Comment: i modified things but thanks a lot .. Accepted as Answer :) Thanks for your Time

Comment: useful.. I just added a View using IB

Answer (score 0):

Please allocate that view out side of the table view methods.
You can add this in view did load.
Then Add this View in the cell's contentView.

It may work..

Comment: can you show me code... bcz your suggestion is not working

Comment: I use objective c.

Comment: This will not help either. no matter where you initialise if you are adding it as subview again and again will result in same.

Comment: please use this  in cellForRowAtIndexPath in starting.......                             for (UIView *vw in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        
        [vw removeFromSuperview];
    }

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the dequeue problem. Whenever you add a subview in cellForRowAtIndexPath method you have to check the condition whether the view is already added as SubView or not if it is already added then you have to remove the subview and add it again.